# Inaccurate plot in MATLAB, not showing correct points

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I am trying to plot a function in `MATLAB` and mark the root with an 'x'. The function I am  plotting is

```
  y = (1+(sqrt(9-x.^2)/sqrt(4-x.^2))-sqrt(9-x.^2))
```

here is my code:

```
x = 0:0.00001:2;
y =  1+(sqrt(9-x.^2)/sqrt(4-x.^2))-sqrt(9-x.^2);
x_marker = 1.2311;
y_marker = 0;
plot(x,y,'-',x_marker,y_marker,'x'),grid;
```

The root of my function is approximately `x = 1.2311` however the `MATLAB` plot shows the root to be around 1.4. I have no idea why this happening.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using matrix division, `/`, instead of element-wise division: `./`.

Define `y` as

```
y =  1+(sqrt(9-x.^2)./sqrt(4-x.^2))-sqrt(9-x.^2);  %// note the . that has been added
```

And you will get the graph you expect. (note you should probably adjust the range of `x` to end at around `1.5`)